# How to match to root with a subdomain contraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to match to the root path when I have a subdomain constraint, so am trying

```
# config/routes.rb
root to : '/'
match '/', to: 'blogs#show', via: :get contraints: {subdomain: /.+/} }
```

but if I put `some_subdomain.mywebsite.com/` into the browser, it just goes to the normal home page.  On the other hand if I do

```
# config/routes.rb
match '/info', to: 'blogs#show', via: :get contraints: {subdomain: /.+/} }
```

and put `some_subdomain.mywebsite.com/info` into the browser, it does go the blog show page.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the root definition after the matcher i.e.

```
# config/routes.rb
match '/', to: 'blogs#show', via: :get contraints: {subdomain: /.+/} }
root to : '/'
```